# Store serializable data in char or string variable in Java

Tags: java, javascript

```
Serializable a = randomForest.getClassificationByMaxProb(attributes);  
System.out.println("Assigned class: " + a);
```

I am getting the result:

```
Assigned class: 1
```

I want to store that class which is `1` into any `char` or `int` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a contains 1, which means toString() method return 1, you can do the following

> int iSerizable = Integer.parseInt(a.toString());